# Error in webdriver.Chrome() After updated my Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04

I have recently updated my Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 when I am trying  to run the driver = webdriver.Chrome()

```
I am using the Python Selenium and getting the following error:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 67, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 87, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 141, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unrecognized Blink revision: d65a1c2f313b54fb0b90bb8a1082e4f5ecba2dda
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267518,platform=Linux 4.4.0-21-generic x86_64)
```

Can any one pleas help me out with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

That's an old version of chromedriver, first things first, download the latest chromedriver, add it to the system path.